# EXP-0003 No storage definition found for segment (0,0) error while using EXP for export

Tags: database, oracle11g, export

I am trying to export a schema using EXP command on the server which is throwing me error EXP-0003 No storage definition found for segment (0,0).

exp userid=user/pass@SID file=vmper01cm_30Sep2015.dmp log=vmper01cm_30Sep2015.log statistics=NONE

The export release it shows me is -- Export Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Sep 30 02:38::31 2015

and Database is

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

I am not sure if it is because of the varying version of export release and database release or there is another cause for it.

The error are also showing for tables where are no rows (empty tables).

I have later perform an export on our 10g machine where the export release and database release are same and it says export terminated with no warnings.

This is for 10g database

Export: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Sep 28 12:01:09 2015

Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

Answer (score 1):

You should use exp version 11.2.0.4.0(the same as the server has), although in this case it more looks like a bug in Oracle's exp utility.

AFAIK you have problem with "SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED" table parameter.
These tables allocate the space on demand, when the 1st row is inserted in to them. This is 11g feature.

You can call:

```
alter table <table name> allocate extent;
```

as workaround.

Comment: ohh got it but how you figure it out i mean i was also browsing on internet and then i see this solution also but i dont know if this is the real problem or the version difference. For this i have to do it for each table and i have almost 370 tables in my schema i think for that i need to write a plsql block

Comment: AFAIK the real problem is that the early version of `exp` tool can not cope with the new 11g feature. Anyway you always should use the same version, otherwise you can not guarantee, that exp will understand the format of Oracle metadata.

Comment: Yeah that is the major problem so how can i change the version of export release ? i mean to whom should i contact i my organization to update the export release ! and i have use the ALTER command given by use it with a plSQL block for all the tables now it is processing the tables zero (0) also.but i think its not a proper solution for the problem. THANKS